# Extract values of different columns

Tags: r, extract

I want to extract values from different columns, depending on the value of column `x`. This column is in a dataframe 1 and contains different factor levels (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6). The columns where I want to extract the values from are in dataframe 2. Examples of both dataframes:

Dataframe 1 is called `istrata` (173 rows)

```
    > istrata[1:5,]
       POSCODN  Geslacht    Agegrp
    1    2651   0.4761905      1
    2    2651   0.4761905      5
    3    2652   0.5785124      1
    4    2652   0.5785124      1
    5    2661   0.5270758      3
```

Dataframe 2 is called `strata` with (1721 rows):

```
     > strata[1:5,]
         POSCODN   Geslacht   agegrp_1   agegrp_2   agegrp_3   agegrp_4   agegrp_5    agegrp_6
    1      2651 0.4761905 0.34085213 0.10025063 0.13784461 0.27318296 0.13784461 0.010025063
    2      2652 0.5785124 0.34710744 0.23966942 0.11570248 0.19008264 0.10743802 0.000000000
    3      2661 0.5270758 0.36462094 0.13357401 0.15162455 0.25270758 0.09747292 0.000000000
    4      2662 0.6229508 0.39344262 0.26229508 0.11475410 0.21311475 0.01639344 0.000000000
    5      2665 0.5387931 0.28448276 0.08189655 0.17241379 0.31465517 0.13362069 0.012931034
```

So in the end I want to achieve that when in the first row of dataframe 1, `Agegrp` is 1, it imputes the value of the dataframe 2 from row 1 (since similar POSCODN), column 3 (`agegrp_1`). Another example, row 5 in dataframe 1 is in `Agegrp 5` and has `POSCODN` 2661. So here it should look at row 3 in dataframe 2 and column 4 (`agegrp_3`) See the dataframe example below (an addition to `istrata`):

```
      Geslacht     I_Agegrp 
1     0.4761905   0.34085213
2     0.4761905   0.13784461
3     0.5785124   0.34710744
4     0.5785124   0.34710744
5     0.5270758   0.15162455
```

Is there a way to do this?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use a 2-dimensional matrix as an index `df[cbind(seq_along(x), x+1L)]`

Answer (score 2):

From the help for `?'['`:

> When indexing arrays by [ a single argument i can be a matrix with as
>   many columns as there are dimensions of x; the result is then a vector
>   with elements corresponding to the sets of indices in each row of i.

So the subset can be a matrix. column 1 will be the rows and column 2 will represent the columns.

If x is `x <- c(3,2,1,1,1)`, we can combine that with the rows `1:nrow(df)`. The matrix will look like:

```
cbind(1:nrow(df), x)
       x
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 1
[4,] 4 1
[5,] 5 1
```

If we used this matrix to subset `df[cbind(1:nrow(df), x)]`, the first extraction will be `df[1,3]`, the second extraction `df[2,2]` and so on. But we need to account for the `Gender` column and add 1 to the second column, `x + 1`.

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), x+1)]
[1] 0.1378446 0.2396694 0.3646209 0.3934426 0.2844828
```

**Edit**

With the new names:

```
strata[cbind(1:nrow(strata), istrata$Agegrp + 1L)]
```

Comment: Thanks, only I am still a bit lost. Does `df` refers to dataframe 1 or dataframe 2? And `x+1` does not work, since the column names in dataframe 2 are different. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes `df` is just an example data frame name. `x` is for the column with `3 2 1 1 1`. You did not provide any data frame names so I used a default name. If you would like me to literally write all of your code for you. give me the names of both with the relevant column names.

Comment: Thanks, because I do not see completely understand what to change. I updated my post with the dataframe and columnnames and the first 5 rows of the data.

Comment: You still haven't added the output. What is the new vector that should come from that example.

Comment: I have edited the post with all the information, hope this is better